# React useContext - access nested Object (undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a backend guy, attempting my very first react/JS app.

I'm attempting to pass some auth data from AuthContext to use in a fetch in another component and I can't for the life of me work out why not.

`user` is a nested object like so:
[image: user]

I can access the first level objects like user.username, but going any deeper like user.signInUserSession.accessToken I get undefined every time.

I can even access the jwtToken in react dev tools with `$r.hooks[0].value.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken`.

AuthContext.js

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";

export const AuthContext = createContext(false);

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState([false]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(user => setUser(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );

};
export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Body.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import {Content} from "./styles"
import {AuthContext} from "../../../contexts/AuthContext";


function Body() {
    const user = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [investor, setInvestor] = useState([]);

    const jwtToken = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken;

    useEffect(() => console.log("Bearer ".concat(jwtToken)), [user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://DOMAIN/investors/overview/v3/?token=".concat(jwtToken), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer ".concat(jwtToken)
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                setInvestor(responseData);
            })
            .catch(error => setInvestor({ error }));
    }, [user]);

    return (
        <Content>{investor.total_value}</Content>
    )
}

export default Body
```

Any help on what I'm missing is much appreciated!

EDIT - Actual Object copied from devTools (not sure how to inspect the actual user object directly other than this?):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Context",
    "value": {
      "username": "XXX",
      "pool": "{advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true, client: …}",
      "Session": null,
      "client": "{endpoint: \"https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amaz…}",
      "signInUserSession": {
        "idToken": {
          "jwtToken": "MDRjYmUiLCJhdWQiOiI0dmRwbmo2b2JhaGpyc25hbmtkNvdXRoZUiOiJwb3dlcndy...",
          "payload": "{aud: \"4vdpnj6obahjrsnankda91s2va\", auth_time: 1583…}",
          "constructor": "ƒ CognitoIdToken() {}",
          "getJwtToken": "ƒ getJwtToken() {}",
          "getExpiration": "ƒ getExpiration() {}",
          "getIssuedAt": "ƒ getIssuedAt() {}",
          "decodePayload": "ƒ decodePayload() {}"
        },
        "refreshToken": {
          "token": "iJKXkXkGbJbBgnRPMN84TWBdsES-mZBGN3yxGd-6555-a67nsFuB9UZKG-s-mk3EHRqs-WfeDxpOw9ia5OtI-ZZTNh2pK...",
          "getToken": "ƒ getToken() {}"
        },
        "accessToken": {
          "jwtToken": "GET_THIS_TOKEN.zb3V0aGVhc3QtMi5hbWpIjoi...",
          "payload": "{auth_time: 1583469821, client_id: n…}",
          "constructor": "ƒ CognitoAccessToken() {}",
          "getJwtToken": "ƒ getJwtToken() {}",
          "getExpiration": "ƒ getExpiration() {}",
 .........
```

Comment: Instead of screenshot , could you please post the actual object?

Comment: added and redacted - from devtools

Comment: You can access, `accessToken` using -> `console.log(response[0].value.signInUserSession.accessToken);`.